# Dojo accessing variable from external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo

I am migrating to Dojo 10.4, before I have few customized javascript files which are modified by running dojo amd converter. But after migrating I cannot able to access variables in js files.

I have declared like this in a file called abc:

`define([
    "dojo",
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/request",
    "dijit/form/FilteringSelect"
], function (dojo, declare, lang, on, request, FilteringSelect) {
        var VARIABLE= {};`

Now I am using this js file in jsp file by integrating with `<script>`command.

the main problem is, how can I access the var VARIABLE in the jsp file.

I have tried with require, provide etc..but still cannot access the declared variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you worked with javascript objects, then you can understand:

Here `var VARIABLE` is defined as a private variable, if you need it in JSP, you have to make it public. Here is an example snippet for it.

in ui/some.js:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dijit/form/FilteringSelect"
],function( declare, lang, FilteringSelect){
    return declare("ui.some", [],{
        VARIABLE: "testing",
    });
});
```

In index.jsp:

```
require(["ui/some"],function(Some){
    alert(Some.VARIABLE);
});
```

Comment: Note that there is no need to use `declare` in absolutely every module; modules can return plain JavaScript objects, functions, etc. too.  The gist of the answer is that the variable needs to actually be exposed via the module's return value.